# What is the best way to implement a 2D grid of radio buttons?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, radio-button, selecteditem

What is the best way to implement a 2D grid of radio buttons so that only one option in each column and one option in each row can be selected?

Comment: There are some behavior problems(assuming behavior is relevant):
1. Suppose a radio button in (1, 2) is selected.
2. Also, a radio button in (2, 1) is selected too.
3. The user pressed (1, 1). But both radio buttons in row and column are selected. Should it ignore the input or unselect one(which)?

Comment: Since he's tagged it winforms, it can normally be assumed that it's a .net problem.

Comment: @friol, @Jeffrey - Correct, .Net, and just for the sake of discussion, let's say C#.

Comment: @luiscubal - Pressing (1, 1) would move the selection for row 1 to its column 1 and for column 1 to its row 1. Let's now consider a 3x3 grid where the diagonal (1, 1), (2, 2) and (3, 3) are selected. Now a user selects button (1, 3) [(r, c)]. This then makes col 1 and row 3 undefined (no selection).

Comment: (cont...) The user would need to make new selections in these. I recognize the potential for confusion for the user. I would call attention to the needed input.

Answer (score 2):

A 1D array of 1D arrays of radio buttons.  Each row (or column) would use the normal radio button functionality, while each column (or row) would be updated by a loop called whenever an individual radio button is toggled.

Comment: I would use JavaScript (e.g., jQuery) to disable clicks that would cause two buttons to be active on the same column (or row) - plus a backend check

Comment: @WalterTross Most browsers don't have a way to un-select a radio button, so it would be tedious or impossible to shuffle selections around to conform if some clicks were not allowed.

Comment: why would you need to un-select radio buttons? Simply disabling clicks would be enough

Comment: @WalterTross if the array is square and you have already made a selection in each row (and thus in each column) then your solution would trap the user with no way to change their selections.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program {

    static RadioButton[] bs = new RadioButton[9];

    static void HandleCheckedChanged (object o, EventArgs a) {
        RadioButton b = o as RadioButton;
        if (b.Checked) {
            Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(bs, b));
        }
    }

    static void Main () {
        Form f = new Form();
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int n = bs.Length;
        while (i < n) {
            bs[i] = new RadioButton();
            bs[i].Parent = f;
            bs[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            bs[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(HandleCheckedChanged);
            if ((i % 3) == 2) {
                x = 0;
                y += bs[i].Height;
            } else {
                x += bs[i].Width;
            }
            i++;
        }
        Application.Run(f);
    }

}
```

Regards,
tamberg

Comment: This creates a single 2D button group which allows only one button in the entire group to be selected. In my question, I specified that it should be one per row and one per column (that would be a total of three selected out of nine buttons in six groups, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this with a custom collection and databind the radio buttons.

Each individual child would have a property for row and a property for column as well as the true/false value flag, which raises an event when changed to true via a click or keypress.

Logic in the collection class would respond to the value change and loop through the other children in the same row and column to notify them that they should be false.

If you don't want to databind, you could also do it with a collection of user controls.